# Using a function() variable in a different Class - Swift

Tags: swift, global-variables

How can I use the value of getLevel() inside the customView class? This function is linked with an NSTimer. The values are the decibel values of an mp3 file, which I want to use inside customView to sync the decibels values with an animation

```
class customView: UIView {

// get getLevels() value

}


class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



   var bundle = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("guitar", ofType: "mp3")!)
   var error: NSError? = nil
   player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: bundle), error: &error)
   player.delegate = self
   player.volume = 1.0
   player.meteringEnabled = true
   player.play()



    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("getLevel"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


func getLevel() {

    if (player.playing == true) {

        player.updateMeters()
        var dblevel = player.averagePowerForChannel(1)
        var percentage = CGFloat( pow(10, (0.05 * dblevel)) * 100)

        // This prints out the the decibel levels from 0.0 to 100.0 every 0.1 sec
        println(percentage)


    }

}
```

The variable I will need is 'percentage'. What are my options to do this? 
Thanks, Godart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments in the code should be all you need to understand this:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    var percentage: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay() // this will cause the system to tell the view to draw itself.
        }
    }

    func drawRect(rect: Rect) {
        // draw yourself based on percentage
    }
}

class ViewController: ... {
    func getLevel() {

        if (player.playing == true) {

            player.updateMeters()
            var dblevel = player.averagePowerForChannel(1)
            var percentage = CGFloat( pow(10, (0.05 * dblevel)) * 100)

            myCustomView.percentage = percentage // this is how to pass the information.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the didSet {} this the job!

Answer (score 0):

Following the Model-View-Controller design pattern, your ViewController should be responsible for handling model information and passing it to your view to display the info to the user.  Therefore, you should create a variable in your view controller class to store the CustomView:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   // new var to store the customView if you're using Storyboards
   @IBOutlet var customView: CustomView!
   // new var to store the customView without using Storyboards
   var customView: CustomView?

   var bundle = NSString(string: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("guitar", ofType: "mp3")!)
   var error: NSError? = nil
   player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: bundle), error: &error)
   player.delegate = self
   player.volume = 1.0
   player.meteringEnabled = true
   player.play()



    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("getLevel"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

This will allow you to update the values in your CustomView directly from your controller and you can use the `getLevel()` method to do so.  If you only need the `percentage` value from within the function, then I suggest you calculate the percentage in its own method so you can use the percentage in multiple places without repeating code.

```
func calculatePercentage() -> CGFloat {

  let dblevel = player.averagePowerForChannel(1)

  return CGFloat(pow(10, (0.05 * dblevel)) * 100)

}
```

Then you can use the method instead of typing the same code over and over.

```
func getLevel() {

  if (player.playing == true) {

    player.updateMeters()
    let percentage = calculatePercentage()

    // This prints out the decibel levels from 0.0 to 100.0 every 0.1 sec
    println(percentage)

  }

}
```

Somewhere in your view controller when you're ready to update your view, you can pass the percentage like this:

```
self.customView.updateView(percentage: calculatePercentage())
```